# How to shift subviews downwards if a subview goes out of screen bounds in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, for-loop, uiimageview

I am working on a view which displays multiple images on Imageview and the count of the images is dynamic. 
   I am getting those images through URL and the URL's string are stored in an array.

I have taken a for loop for creating a new imageview for every single image to display on it. The frame of the imageview is set on the basis of the size of the images. but the problem is that, when  the count of images goes beyond 5, the sixth image goes out of the screen. But i want it to move downwards if there are more than 5 images in the array.

Here below is my code for displaying images on imageview using for-loop

```
int x=0;
for (int i=0;i<[items count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"image name %@",[items objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSLog(@"image url  %@",[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[items objectAtIndex:i]]]);

    NSString* urlTextEscaped = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[items objectAtIndex:i]] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *imgData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlTextEscaped]];        

    UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imgData]];
    imgV.frame=CGRectMake(x, 0, 50, 50);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgV];
    x=x+imgV.frame.size.width+10;
}
```

Comment: why you are not using table view or scrollview ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift as this images

```
int x=0;
int y =0;
 for (int i=0;i<[items count]; i++)
{
  NSLog(@"image name %@",[items objectAtIndex:i]);
  NSLog(@"image url  %@",[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[items objectAtIndex:i]]]);

   NSString* urlTextEscaped = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[items objectAtIndex:i]] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSData *imgData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlTextEscaped]];        

   UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imgData]];
   imgV.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 50, 50);
   [cell.contentView addSubview:imgV];
   if(x>cell.frame.size.width)
     {
         x =0;
         y= y+imgV.frame.size.height+10;
     }
     else
     {
      x=x+imgV.frame.size.width+10;

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the images inside a scrollview or a tableview so that when there are many images and you are not able to fit all those images in the screen. Then it will have the scroll functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards, add a ***scrollview*** to your viewController's view and then use then this sample code should help you.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:YES];

    [self addView:15];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) addView:(NSInteger)numberOfViews
{
    double x =10 , y=10;

    for (NSInteger i=1; i <= numberOfViews; i++) {
        UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 50, 50)];
        y = y+70;
        [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
        [_scrollView addSubview:view];
    }
}
@end
```

> Note: In interface builder,click your scrollview, then Attributes inspector and check (tick) the **Bounce Vertically** option under *Scroll View* section